# Hybris Commerce Cuppy extension installation failure

Tags: java, xml, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud

My Environment: Win10 + Java 8 + Hybris Commerse 6.3

I've followed the tutorial steps available on https://help.hybris.com for the Cuppy installation. And after rebuild and launch of the application I faced the following exception:

```
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema or spring-security-3.2.xsd schema or spring-security-4.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 4.1. Please update your schema declarations to the 4.1 schema.
Offending resource: class path resource [cuppy/cuppy-spring-security.xml]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:60) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: 
Root WebApplicationContext - /cuppy: startup date [Thu Mar 30 13:15:10 EEST 2017]; parent: hybris Application context - master
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Cuppy extension was not upgraded for spring security 4.1 
Cuppy has the following configuration in cuppy-spring-security.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"
```

and it should be changed to the following

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"
```

Comment: That's strange, I've a lot of reference to `spring-security-4.0.xsd` in my 6.3 installation and it works fine...